# Accessing Turtlebot iRobot Create Sensors

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, move-base, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that when navigating with the gmapping demo or amcl demo that the turtlebot stops when the wheel drop sensors or bump sensors are active, just wondering if anyone knows what node takes care of this (move_base?) and what source file it can be found in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37742/accessing-turtlebot-irobot-create-sensors/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot handles this in the [Turtlebot Node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node), which forms the ROS interface to the iRobot Create hardware.

The most relevant bits are:

[Line 398](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#l398) and forward, where if there is a `cmd_vel` to be sent to the hardware, it first executes the `self.check_bumpers` function at [Line 429](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#l429).

```
def check_bumpers(self, s, cmd_vel):
    # Safety: disallow forward motion if bumpers or wheeldrops
    # are activated.
    # TODO: check bumps_wheeldrops flags more thoroughly, and disable
    # all motion (not just forward motion) when wheeldrops are activated
    forward = (cmd_vel[0] + cmd_vel[1]) > 0
    if self.stop_motors_on_bump and s.bumps_wheeldrops > 0 and forward:
        return (0,0)
    else:
        return cmd_vel
```

The actual hardware interaction is taking place in the [roomba_sensor_handler.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/roomba_sensor_handler.py) file or the [create_sensor_handler.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_node/src/turtlebot_node/create_sensor_handler.py) file, also in the `turtlebot_node` package.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-03**:
thanks a lot